# Upgrading dompdf from 0.6 to 0.8, pdf generation now extremely slow

Tags: pdf, drupal, drupal-7, dompdf

We are upgrading PHP from 7.0 to 7.4, and as part of that, upgrading dompdf from 0.6.2 to the latest version as I write this, 0.8.6. A web page that used to take seconds to generate a PDF is now taking more than 15 minutes to execute $root->reflow() in the render() method. That seems wrong, like that there must be a configuration error or a new option not set or something of that kind.

This is coming from a Drupal 7 website using the Print module to call dompdf, so the HTML and CSS are not easily tweaked.

Any thoughts anyone has about settings to look at, or about what might be going wrong, would be appreciated.

update: I added a line to render() to save the HTML to a file, and then used the quick start script code to load that HTML and create a PDF. It takes seconds to run. So I'm at a loss.

```
<?php
require_once 'sites/all/libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
$html = file_get_contents('dompdf.1608229811.html');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
file_put_contents('mydomtest.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

Comment: i'm sure that's true but the CSS hasn't changed and the speed has Drastically changed.

Comment: is the css external or inline?

Comment: also show what are the contents of the html if possible

Comment: I don't know that this is *the* answer, but we got some clues from the fact that the same code was not so slow on the actual live website. The local development version was running as https with a self-signed certificate. Dompdf was making HTTP requests that were failing as a result. When I added a stream context to skip certificate validation, it helped quite a bit. See the Print module issue "Add print_pdf_dompdf_alter hook to support dompdf object access": https://www.drupal.org/project/print/issues/3201297